# problems implementing pundit gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

been trying to implament the pundit gem in rails, its not showing up in my index page and not sure why, my error message says

```
1) Error:
DeletingAPost Feature Test#test_0001_delete the post:
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link or button "Destroy"
    /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:41:in `block in find'
    /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:81:in `synchronize'
    /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:30:in `find'
    /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:13:in `click_link_or_button'
    /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:354:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
    /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
    /Users/cheatermoves/newHW/Portfolio/test/features/post_delete_post_test.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

here is a copy of my index html post page

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr id="<%= dom_id(post) %>">
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <% if policy(post).update? %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <% end %>
    <% if policy(post).destroy? %>
       <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

here are copies of my policy pages

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "must be logged in" unless user
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end
end

class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Struct.new(:user, :scope)
    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

my user model that I installed with devise and my posts model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :role, :published

  def author?
    role == 'author'
  end

  def editor?
    role == 'editor'
  end
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: "author_id"
end


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"

  def publish!
    published = true
    save!
  end
end
```

and also my posts controller

sorry figuring this out to me is like finding a needle in a hay stack can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer on old post, but for this, your destroy? policy is automatically false (you don't have a destroy? in the post policy, so, you fall back to the ApplicationPolicy), so the delete button is never created no matter who the user is.

Answer (score -1):

You signed off LimeChat so I couldn't answer you live, the logic that was added to the view says that they should only populate for users who should have access to those actions.  So you can try to make your signed in user for the test, an editor fixture, because now in theory they're the only users that should see those buttons populate.